# AngularJS Error with multiple controllers and Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, controllers

Unable to get the multiple controllers to work with Grunt.  Grunt is not the issue though, as simply combining the files manually does not work either.  I am trying to build the application with Grunt and single controllers with one per file to build out the application over time.

The controllers are in individual files that are combined and minified with Grunt.  This works, and the module looks correct before it is minified.  The unminified example is in the script.js.

I am getting the error below:
Error: error:unpr
Unknown Provider

```
'use strict';
angular.module('OntarioDarts', []);

// Source: app/Modules/Events/EventController.js
angular.module('OntarioDarts').controller('EventCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Events = [
        {
            'Id': 1,
            'Name': '12th Annual Frank Hanlon Tournament',
            'Date': 20150117,
            'Time': 1000,
            'Image': 'images/Events/FrankHanlon20150128.jpg',
            'Flyer': ''
        },
        {
            'Id': 2,
            'Name': '1st Annual Ken Cadieux Memorial Christmas Tournament',
            'Date': 20141227,
            'Time': 1000,
            'Image': 'images/Events/KenCadieux20141227.jpg',
            'Flyer': ''

        },
        {
            'Id': 3,
            'Name': '8th Annual Presidents Cup Tournament',
            'Date': 20150313,
            'Time': 2000,
            'Image': 'images/Events/PresidentsCup20150314.jpg',
            'Flyer': ''
        }
    ];
    $scope.ImageSettings = [{ 'Height': 200, 'Width': 155 }];
});

// Source: app/Modules/Leagues/LeagueController.js
angular.module('OntarioDarts').controller('LeagueCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Leagues = [
        { 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Dixie Summer Dart League' },
        { 'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Etobicoke Pub Dart League'  },
        { 'Id': 3, 'Name': 'Region of Peel Dart League'}
    ];
});

// Source: app/Modules/Schedules/ScheduleController.js
angular.module('OntarioDarts').controller('ScheduleCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Schedules = [
        { "Id": 1, "Name": "November 1, 2014" },
        { "Id": 2, "Name": "November 5, 2014" }
    ];
});

// Source: app/Modules/Teams/TeamController.js
angular.module('OntarioDarts').controller('TeamCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Teams = [
        { 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'Team 1' },
        { 'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Team 2' }
    ];
});

//# sourceMappingURL=OntarioDarts.js.map
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/SDLycGpskrPXqx9Ppf31)

Comment: When you say it doesn't work when 'combining the files manually' , does that include minifying ? Normally you need to use angular's inline annotations or use a minifier that is angular aware for dependency injection to work.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with not having the array notation on the controller (see the answer below).  When I had it in one file it worked properly (similar to the tutorial) so I mistakingly though it was due to the splitting then combining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Q0WTfLzjsJ4ZnGDnxzz?p=preview) that file name is script.js instead of scripts.js. that is referenced wrongly in html.

Please consider this when you minify

Following is the safest way to write for minification

```
angular.module('OntarioDarts').controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   //controller code goes here
}]);
```

you have to use array notation for your controller function to understand $scope.

```
['$scope', function ($scope) {
   //controller code goes here
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, scripts was a typo from the plunker interface where I used the built in file instead of my own name as my code does.  The array notation corrected my issue. Thank you.